# iHow to split multiline text in R?

Tags: r, split

I have one input file which has one paragraph. I need to split paragraph by pattern into two sub-paragraphs.

paragraph.xml

```
 <Text>
      This is first line.
      This is second line.
      \delemiter\new\one
      This is third line.
      This is fourth line.
 </Text>
```

R code:

```
doc<-xmlTreeParse("paragraph.xml")
top = xmlRoot(doc)
text<-top[[1]]
```

I need to split this paragraph into 2 paragraphs.

paragraph1

```
 This is first line.
 This is second line.
```

paragraph2

```
  This is third line.
  This is fourth line.
```

I found strsplit function is very useful but it never split multi line text.

Comment: Is this a `character` of length one with embedded newlines, a list or vector of `character`, or a text file that you have yet to read in?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact structure of your data (or some example data). For example, paste in the results of `dput(head(yourdata))`. Currently it's not clear how the new lines are determined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have xml files, it is better to use `XML` package facilities. I see you start using it here a continuity of what you have start.

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse('paragraph.xml') ## equivalent xmlTreeParse (...,useInternalNodes =TRUE)
## extract the text of the node Text
mytext = xpathSApply(doc,'//Text/text()',xmlValue)
## convert it to a list of lines using scan
lines <- scan(text=mytext,sep='\n',what='character')
## get the delimiter index
delim <- which(lines == "\\delemiter\\new\\one")
## get the 2 paragraphes
p1 <- lines[seq(delim-1)]
p2 <- lines[seq(delim+1,length(lines))]
```

Then you can use `paste` or `write` to get the paragraph structure, for example, using `write`:

```
write(p1,"",sep='\n')

This is first line.
This is second line.
```

Comment: can i use cat instead of suing write function to get paragraph structure?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sort of roundabout possibility, using `split`, `grepl`, and `cumsum`.

Some sample data:

```
temp <- c("This is first line.", "This is second line.", 
          "\\delimiter\\new\\one", "This is third line.", 
          "This is fourth line.", "\\delimiter\\new\\one",
          "This is fifth line")
# [1] "This is first line."   "This is second line."  "\\delimiter\\new\\one"
# [4] "This is third line."   "This is fourth line."  "\\delimiter\\new\\one"
# [7] "This is fifth line"
```

Use `split` after generating "groups" by using `cumsum` on `grepl`:

```
temp1 <- split(temp, cumsum(grepl("delimiter", temp)))
temp1
# $`0`
# [1] "This is first line."  "This is second line."
# 
# $`1`
# [1] "\\delimiter\\new\\one" "This is third line."   "This is fourth line." 
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "\\delimiter\\new\\one" "This is fifth line"
```

If further cleanup is desired, here's one option:

```
lapply(temp1, function(x) {
  x[grep("delimiter", x)] <- NA
  x[complete.cases(x)]
})
# $`0`
# [1] "This is first line."  "This is second line."
# 
# $`1`
# [1] "This is third line."  "This is fourth line."
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "This is fifth line"
```